# AndEngine physics - my character shakes while moving

Tags: box2d, sprite, andengine, physics

I have a problem with physics in AndEngine. My sprite shakes while moving and sometimes jumps. I made my 'floor' of boxes 32x32 and everyone is another body, so I thought this is the issue (some collision with their corners or something). I've tried to use one shape instead of those boxes, but the problem remains.

It looks like the surfece of my floor is not straight but somehow irregular...

My question is, how to make my character move smoothly on this surface?

And by the way, how to make my character heavier?

My whole code is here:

```
private final int CAMERA_WIDTH = 800;
private final int CAMERA_HEIGHT = 480;

enum PlayerAction {
    RUN,
    NONE,
    JUMP
}

enum Direction {
    RIGHT,
    LEFT,
    NONE
}

enum BodyId {
    PLAYER,
    BOX
}

Direction mPlayerDirection = Direction.NONE;
Direction mLastPlayerDirection = Direction.NONE;

private Camera mCamera;
private Scene mGameScene;

private PhysicsWorld mPhysicsWorld;

private BitmapTextureAtlas mBoxBitmapTextureAtlas;
private BitmapTextureAtlas mPlayerBitmapTextureAtlas;
private ITextureRegion mBoxTextureRegion;
private TiledTextureRegion mPlayerTextureRegion;

private AnimatedSprite mPlayer;
private Body mPlayerBody;

private BitmapTextureAtlas mOnScreenControlTexture;
private ITextureRegion mOnScreenControlBaseTextureRegion;
private ITextureRegion mOnScreenControlKnobTextureRegion;

private AnalogOnScreenControl mAnalogOnScreenControl;

@Override
public EngineOptions onCreateEngineOptions() {

    this.mCamera = new Camera(0, 0, CAMERA_WIDTH, CAMERA_HEIGHT);
    EngineOptions mEngineOptions = new EngineOptions(true, ScreenOrientation.LANDSCAPE_FIXED, new FillResolutionPolicy(), this.mCamera);
    mEngineOptions.getTouchOptions().setNeedsMultiTouch(true);

    return mEngineOptions;
}
@Override
public void onCreateResources(
        OnCreateResourcesCallback pOnCreateResourcesCallback)
        throws Exception {

    BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.setAssetBasePath("gfx/");
    this.mBoxBitmapTextureAtlas = new BitmapTextureAtlas(this.getTextureManager(), 32, 32, TextureOptions.BILINEAR);
    this.mBoxTextureRegion = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createFromAsset(this.mBoxBitmapTextureAtlas, this, "box.png", 0, 0);
    this.mBoxBitmapTextureAtlas.load();

    this.mPlayerBitmapTextureAtlas = new BitmapTextureAtlas(this.getTextureManager(), 256, 128, TextureOptions.BILINEAR);
    this.mPlayerTextureRegion = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createTiledFromAsset(this.mPlayerBitmapTextureAtlas, this, "player.png", 0, 0, 3, 4);
    this.mPlayerBitmapTextureAtlas.load();

    this.mOnScreenControlTexture = new BitmapTextureAtlas(this.getTextureManager(), 256, 128, TextureOptions.BILINEAR);
    this.mOnScreenControlBaseTextureRegion = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createFromAsset(this.mOnScreenControlTexture, this, "onscreen_control_base.png", 0, 0);
    this.mOnScreenControlKnobTextureRegion = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createFromAsset(this.mOnScreenControlTexture, this, "onscreen_control_knob.png", 128, 0);
    this.mOnScreenControlTexture.load();

    pOnCreateResourcesCallback.onCreateResourcesFinished();
}
@Override
public void onCreateScene(OnCreateSceneCallback pOnCreateSceneCallback)
        throws Exception {

    this.mGameScene = new Scene();

    initPhysics(this.mGameScene);

    for(int i = 0; i <= 50; i++) {
        Sprite sprite = new Sprite(i*32, this.mCamera.getHeight() - this.mBoxTextureRegion.getHeight(), this.mBoxTextureRegion, this.getVertexBufferObjectManager());
        createBody(sprite, BodyType.StaticBody, 1, 0, 0, BodyId.BOX);
        this.mGameScene.attachChild(sprite);
    }

    /* Calculate the coordinates for the face, so its centered on the camera. */
    final float playerX = (CAMERA_WIDTH - this.mPlayerTextureRegion.getWidth()) / 2;
    final float playerY = CAMERA_HEIGHT - this.mPlayerTextureRegion.getHeight() - 128;

    this.mPlayer = new AnimatedSprite(playerX, playerY, this.mPlayerTextureRegion, this.getVertexBufferObjectManager()) {

        @Override
        protected void onManagedUpdate(float pSecondsElapsed) {
            super.onManagedUpdate(pSecondsElapsed);
            switch (mPlayerDirection) {
            case RIGHT:
                if (!mPlayerDirection.equals(mLastPlayerDirection)) {
                    mLastPlayerDirection = Direction.RIGHT;
                    GameActivity.this.mPlayer.animate(new long[]{200, 200, 200}, 3, 5, true);
                }
                break;
            case LEFT:
                if (!mPlayerDirection.equals(mLastPlayerDirection)) {
                    mLastPlayerDirection = Direction.LEFT;
                    GameActivity.this.mPlayer.animate(new long[]{200, 200, 200}, 9, 11, true);
                }
                break;
            case NONE:
                mLastPlayerDirection = Direction.NONE;
                GameActivity.this.mPlayer.setCurrentTileIndex(6);
                GameActivity.this.mPlayer.stopAnimation();
                break;
            default:
                mLastPlayerDirection = Direction.NONE;
                GameActivity.this.mPlayer.setCurrentTileIndex(6);
                GameActivity.this.mPlayer.stopAnimation();
                break;
            }
        }
    };

    this.mPlayer.setScaleCenterY(this.mPlayerTextureRegion.getHeight());
    this.mPlayer.setScale(2);
    this.mGameScene.attachChild(this.mPlayer);

    this.mCamera.setChaseEntity(mPlayer);

    this.mPlayerBody = createMovingBody(this.mPlayer, BodyType.DynamicBody, 1, 0, 0, BodyId.PLAYER);

    this.mAnalogOnScreenControl = new AnalogOnScreenControl(32, CAMERA_HEIGHT - this.mOnScreenControlBaseTextureRegion.getHeight() - 32, this.mCamera, this.mOnScreenControlBaseTextureRegion, this.mOnScreenControlKnobTextureRegion, 0.1f, 200, this.getVertexBufferObjectManager(), new IAnalogOnScreenControlListener() {
        @Override
        public void onControlChange(final BaseOnScreenControl pBaseOnScreenControl, final float pValueX, final float pValueY) {

            GameActivity.this.mPlayerBody.setLinearVelocity(new Vector2(pValueX*10, GameActivity.this.mPlayerBody.getLinearVelocity().y));

            if (pValueX > 0)
                GameActivity.this.mPlayerDirection = Direction.RIGHT;
            else if (pValueX < 0)
                GameActivity.this.mPlayerDirection = Direction.LEFT;
            else
                GameActivity.this.mPlayerDirection = Direction.NONE;
        }

        @Override
        public void onControlClick(
                AnalogOnScreenControl pAnalogOnScreenControl) {
            GameActivity.this.mPlayerBody.setLinearVelocity(new Vector2(GameActivity.this.mPlayerBody.getLinearVelocity().x, -8.0f));
        }
    });

    this.mAnalogOnScreenControl.getControlBase().setBlendFunction(GLES20.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GLES20.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
    this.mAnalogOnScreenControl.getControlBase().setAlpha(0.2f);
    this.mAnalogOnScreenControl.getControlBase().setScaleCenter(0, 128);
    this.mAnalogOnScreenControl.getControlBase().setScale(1.25f);
    this.mAnalogOnScreenControl.getControlKnob().setScale(1.25f);
    this.mAnalogOnScreenControl.refreshControlKnobPosition();

    this.mGameScene.setChildScene(this.mAnalogOnScreenControl);

    pOnCreateSceneCallback.onCreateSceneFinished(this.mGameScene);
}
@Override
public void onPopulateScene(Scene pScene,
        OnPopulateSceneCallback pOnPopulateSceneCallback) throws Exception {

    this.mEngine.registerUpdateHandler(new TimerHandler(3f, true, new ITimerCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onTimePassed(TimerHandler pTimerHandler) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

    }));

    pOnPopulateSceneCallback.onPopulateSceneFinished();
}

private void initPhysics(Scene pScene)
{
    mPhysicsWorld = new PhysicsWorld(new Vector2(0, SensorManager.GRAVITY_EARTH), false);
    pScene.registerUpdateHandler(mPhysicsWorld);
}

private Body createBody(Sprite pSprite, BodyType pBodyType, float pDensity, float pElasticity, float pFriction, BodyId pBodyId)
{
    final FixtureDef objectFixtureDef = PhysicsFactory.createFixtureDef(pDensity, pElasticity, pFriction);
    Body body = PhysicsFactory.createBoxBody(this.mPhysicsWorld, pSprite, pBodyType, objectFixtureDef);
    body.setUserData(pBodyId);
    return body;
}

private Body createMovingBody(Sprite pSprite, BodyType pBodyType, float pDensity, float pElasticity, float pFriction, BodyId pBodyId) {
    Body body = createBody(pSprite, pBodyType, pDensity, pElasticity, pFriction, pBodyId);
    mPhysicsWorld.registerPhysicsConnector(new PhysicsConnector(pSprite, body, true, false));
    return body;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this could be caused by insufficient CPU speed. When the processor can't keep up with the demands of Box2D, the simulation suffers. The bodies can fall a little bit into the space occupied by floor and are pushed upwards in the next simulation cycle. This also happens when some background application causes the CPU load to spike.

Try running the application on a faster phone or one without other applications running in background. I solved similar problem using the great MaxStepPhysicsWorld, which can be found here: http://www.andengine.org/forums/features/max-step-physics-to-avoid-choppyness-and-bad-simulation-t1271.html

The way it works is, when the engine is unable to perform enough simulation steps per second, MaxStepPhysicsWorld gives up on being real-time and rather performs enough simulation steps per "second" thus ensuring good simulation.

Comment: Actually I think that my phone is fast enough... I use HTC Sensation, so there shouldn't be any problem with CPU. Other, even much more complicated games with more advanced physics work great! The effect is not kind of lag, but rather it looks like my Sprite was colliding with every box corner, or like my 'ground' was not regular, I don't know why... But I'll give try to fixed-step physics

Comment: Ok. it's much better using MaxStepPhysicsWorld class you linked, but still i have a problem, 'cos sometimes my character stops and i have to jump to make it go further... do you have any idea? thanks a lot for help

Comment: ok, i set my body to circle... i couldn't find any other way, an for now it's quite ok. maybe later i'll simply set the polygon with cut down-left and down-right corners, no need now

Comment: So the character is still getting stuck even when you make the ground from one large box instead of the tiles?

Comment: @daltostronic: Making the body a circle is a neat idea, although the reason for the body getting stuck is a mystery to me.

Answer (score 2):

OKAY I'VE SOLVED IT!

if anybody's interested:
i used function from [here](http://www.andengine.org/forums/development/collision-side-t5156-10.html), because i wanted to check from which side my body collides with others. I changed this function for my use, so:

1. I've modified it's `shrinkToFactor` value usage, so it doesn't actually change size of all the triangles, but make space between corners, so if you touch ground you doesn't collide with 3 triangles, but just with one of them. (but it's another story, maybe somebody needs it or would find useful)
2. I've slightly 'cut' the edges of my bottom fixture, so it slides on edges instead of being stopped by them, here is my bottom fixture vector definition:

   ```
       final Vector2[] vertices2 = { // DOWN
               new Vector2((wd2 - shrinkToFactor - 1) / P2M, (hd2 - 1) / P2M),
               new Vector2((wd2 - shrinkToFactor) / P2M, hd2 / P2M),
               new Vector2((-wd2 + shrinkToFactor) / P2M, hd2 / P2M),
               new Vector2((-wd2 + shrinkToFactor + 1) / P2M, (hd2 - 1) / P2M),
               new Vector2(0 / P2M, 0 / P2M)
       };
   ```

And here is my whole function.

```
    public static Body createPlayerBody(final MaxStepPhysicsWorld pPhysicsWorld, final Sprite pSprite, final FixtureDef pFixtureDef, final float pPixelToMeterRatio, final BodyType bodyType, final float shrinkToFactor) {
        final BodyDef bodyDef = new BodyDef();
        bodyDef.type = bodyType;
        final float P2M = pPixelToMeterRatio;

        final float[] sceneCenterCoordinates = pSprite.getSceneCenterCoordinates();
        bodyDef.position.x = sceneCenterCoordinates[Constants.VERTEX_INDEX_X] / P2M;
        bodyDef.position.y = sceneCenterCoordinates[Constants.VERTEX_INDEX_Y] / P2M;

        final Body boxBody = pPhysicsWorld.createBody(bodyDef);

        final float wd2 = (pSprite.getWidth() / 2);
        final float hd2 = (pSprite.getHeight() / 2);

        final Vector2[] vertices1 = { // RIGHT
                new Vector2(wd2 / P2M, (hd2 - shrinkToFactor) / P2M),
                new Vector2(0 / P2M, 0 / P2M),
                new Vector2(wd2 / P2M, (-hd2 + shrinkToFactor) / P2M)
        };
        final Vector2[] vertices2 = { // DOWN
                new Vector2((wd2 - shrinkToFactor - 1) / P2M, (hd2 - 1) / P2M),
                new Vector2((wd2 - shrinkToFactor) / P2M, hd2 / P2M),
                new Vector2((-wd2 + shrinkToFactor) / P2M, hd2 / P2M),
                new Vector2((-wd2 + shrinkToFactor + 1) / P2M, (hd2 - 1) / P2M),
                new Vector2(0 / P2M, 0 / P2M)
        };
        final Vector2[] vertices3 = { // LEFT
                new Vector2(-wd2 / P2M, (hd2 - shrinkToFactor) / P2M),
                new Vector2(-wd2 / P2M, (-hd2 + shrinkToFactor) / P2M),
                new Vector2(0 / P2M, 0 / P2M)
        };
        final Vector2[] vertices4 = { // UP
                new Vector2((-wd2 + shrinkToFactor) / P2M, -hd2 / P2M),
                new Vector2((wd2 - shrinkToFactor) / P2M, -hd2 / P2M),
                new Vector2(0 / P2M, 0 / P2M)
        };

        PolygonShape poly = new PolygonShape();
        pFixtureDef.shape = poly;
        poly.set(vertices1);
        final Fixture f1 = boxBody.createFixture(pFixtureDef);
        f1.setUserData(BodyId.PLAYER);
        poly.set(vertices2);
        final Fixture f2 = boxBody.createFixture(pFixtureDef);
        f2.setUserData(BodyId.PLAYER_FOOT);
        poly.set(vertices3);
        final Fixture f3 = boxBody.createFixture(pFixtureDef);
        f3.setUserData(BodyId.PLAYER);
        poly.set(vertices4);
        final Fixture f4 = boxBody.createFixture(pFixtureDef);
        f4.setUserData(BodyId.PLAYER_HEAD);
        poly.dispose();

        return boxBody;
}
```

Comment: one more thing may be useful - it's better to use bigger surface pieces (boxes in my game), like 64x64 rather than 32x32